# Angular 2 - Bind array of numbers to select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, data-binding

I have seen a lot of examples to bind array of Objects.

But, all I have is this

```
years = [1900,1901,1902];
```

and i want to bind this to the options for my select control.
I have this template:

```
<select id="carYear" required>
        <option value="">Select year</option>
        <option ngFor="year in years">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```

But, it does not work.

I also tried ng-repeat. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/frishi/bzbbo5da/

Basically, you can use a flat array and enumerate it using a `<select>` 
The only additional thing you need to do is

```
<select ng-model="myYears" ng-options="o as o for o in years"></select>
```

When you use a flat array, you have to tell angular what to use as the key. Angular will do it for you if you use an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an asterisk on the ngFor directive and the let keyword.

Try:

```
<select id="carYear" required>
    <option value="">Select year</option>
    <option *ngFor="let year in years">{{year}}</option>
</select>
```